# Restricting user login by IP address in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a store in Woocommerce with a number of customers having their individual login IDs and Passwords. What I want is to restrict them to login to their store account from a specific IP address only and I dont want them to login from the outside world. 
So for eg., 
IP1---> associated to User1
IP2---> associated to User2
IP3---> associated to User3...and so on...
So that means User1 can login to his store account only when the system detects IP1 as his IP.

I have a function with me but it only detects 1 specific user and 1 specific IP address. I want this function to be modified for array of users associated with the array of IP addresses but the condition is that a particular IP should be associated to one particular user only. That means it should work like: 
IP1->associated with User1 
It should not work like below: 
IP1->should not allow login to User2 or User3 or User4...
Similarly, IP2->should not allow login to User1 or User 3 or User4...
Below is the function:

```
/**
 * Validate IP Address During Authentication - For A Given User 
 */
add_filter( 'authenticate', function( $user )
{
    // Adjust to your needs:
    $allowed_user_ip        = '127.0.0.1';
    $ip_restricted_user_id  = 1;

    // Current user's IP address
    $current_user_ip = isset( $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : null;

    // Nothing to do for valid IP address
    if( $current_user_ip === $allowed_user_ip )
        return $user;

    // Nothing to do for users that are not IP restricted 
    if( 
           $user instanceof \WP_User 
        && $user->ID > 0
        && $ip_restricted_user_id != $user->ID
    )   
        return $user;

    // Add an 'Invalid IP address' error
    if( is_wp_error( $user ) )
        $user->add( 
            'invalid_ip', 
            sprintf(
            '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
            esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
            esc_html__( 'IP address is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
        )
    ); 
    // Create a new 'Invalid IP address' error
    else
        $user = new WP_Error(
            'invalid_ip', 
            sprintf(
                '<strong>%s</strong>: %s',
                esc_html__( 'ERROR', 'mydomain' ),
                esc_html__( 'IP address is invalid.', 'mydomain' )
            )
        ); 

    return $user;
}, 100 );
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: If  a user logs in, and you save his ip address, so that this is linked to the user. 
How do you know or how do you ensure that this is the 'main IP' address? because when someone logs in from another PC for the first time, and wants to do this later from their home location, this will no longer work? what then?

Comment: Is it the intention to add the ip address in code for every user? or do you want to automate this?

Comment: I have fixed number of customers who login from only one IP (their respective IPs) so I would want to hard code their IP address so even if their login information is stolen, they stay safe.

Comment: Any thoughts guys ?